# Keynote doesn't download

Tags: data-transfer, keynote

I deleted Keynote because it didn't update. Then I tried to download Keynote again, but it doesn't. The screen still shows 'update' sign which I saw before Keynote was deleted. How can I download Keynote again?

Comment: What was the exact error message? What macOS are you on?

Comment: It is OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.   The error message is " It's time to update! To open this presentation, you will need a latest version of Keynote."  So I clicked 'upload' button which just keep spinning.

Comment: Actually, this error message appear only when I try to open one file ( so far). But I do need this file.    It is strange that all other files open even though I deleted keynote application (put it in the trash and deleted from the trash as well.

Comment: Ah… that might be a problem. The reason it wouldn't update is because there hasn't been any update for anything that is capable of running on El Capitan in several years. The last version that would run on El Cap is v6.6.2, from 2016. Exactly where were you trying to update it from? App Store, I presume - but the Purchased tab or Updates tab? [The updates tab is broken, btw, nothing you can do to fix it] Purchased should show it as 'Install' if you deleted it. You might need to reboot if it still says 'update' or 'open'.

Comment: btw, If you have been given a file saved from a much newer version, you won't be able to open it on an older version. You'll have to get it in a different format.

Comment: Thank you, Tetsujin (sounds like Japanese name!) .  Yes, I am trying to update from App Store and the Purchased tab shows ' open' .  Sorry I am so beginner.... reboot means restart the computer?

Comment: Yes, try restart & see if that label changes [BTW, yes, that's my Japanese nickname I was given 30 years ago when I worked there - it's from a 1960's cartoon character, Tetsujin Nijuhachiko, which means Iron Man #28 ;))

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I somehow sorted it out by copying Keynote from a backup in USB. My husband is saying I shouldn't store any important files in iCloud. Surely this problem started in iCloud, but iCloud has been fine for me till this problem occurred.  Do you use iCloud ?

Comment: iCloud has no connection at all to his issue. If you need clarification on that, raise it as a new question so more people will see it & be able to answer.